# Ionic ng-click calls same Modal in <input type='button'>

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

```
<label class="item item-input">
 <span class="input-label" id="depTime">Time</span>
 <input type="button" value="{{query.depTime}}" ng-click="openModal(2)" class="button"></input>
 <input type="button" value="{{query.depDate}}" ng-click="openModal(1)" class="button"></input>
</label>
```

openModal function

```
$scope.openModal = function(index) {
        console.log("openModal" + index);
        if (index == 1) {
            $scope.dateModal.show();
        } else {
            $scope.timeModal.show();
        }
    };
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGMQJQ

how does the problem cause?

or I should just use /a class='button'/

thanks for replying

Comment: You shouldn't be using an input tag for a link, but it's probably better to use individual functions, for both clarity, and most probably solve the issue as @Hassan said

Comment: It's an interesting question Matt, I would be interested to know the answer as to why hard-coded parameters cannot be individualised myself. Quill... ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer:

The problem is that you nest two input controls inside the label.
Just remove or replace label around inputs and everything will start working fine

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span class="input-label" id="depTime">Time</span>
  <input type="button" value="{{query.depTime}}" ng-click="openModal(2)" class="button button-outline button-calm"></input>
  <input type="button" value="{{query.depDate}}" ng-click="openModal(1)" class="button button-outline button-calm"></input>
```

See http://codepen.io/ryltsov/pen/aNaxja

Note that i also fixed couple minor bugs (changed modal template dateModal to modal-1 and also updated this modal template to have number 1)

Detailed answer:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html says:

> The label element may contain at most one descendant input element,
>   button element, select element, or textarea element.

Label elements increase the hit area of the related input. If you have two inputs, when you click on either or on the label text the click is handled by the first input. That's why you always get 2 in the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because when you call openModal it always get the value of index=2 it will be better if you use different function for each button then it will work

Comment: Different functions won't change this behavior and won't fix the problem.